# Multiple Bootstrap Modals and postbacks

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

My knowledge in ASP.NET is very limited, yet, I am building a UI/UX design for an application that will be built in ASP MVC and I've heard rumors of the following problem:

> When a Boostrap modal fires a button event (onClick), it creates a postback which in turn, it refreshes the page, thus making it impossible for multiple bootstrap modals to work. Unless the modals do not require to interact with the back end, which means they would simply serve a client-side purpose.

I need to know how much of this is true and if there is a way to create a search or populate a bootstrap modal with information being entered in a second modal.

Unfortunately, I can't produce a working ASP code but I will produce the HTML portion of it so you have an idea.

Again, my question is, can I populate modal 1 with information entered in modal 2? Modal 2 is invoked from Modal 1. See the code and Demo for details

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Working with Multiple Modals</h1>
<div class="margin-lg">
  <button type="button" class="btn-first-modal btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#first-modal">
    Launch Modal
  </button>
</div>


<div class="modal" id="first-modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">First Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <label class="label-control">My ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn-second-modal within-first-modal btn btn-primary">
          Add ID
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="second-modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="btn-second-modal-close close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">ID Generator</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <label class="label-control">Choose ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn-second-modal-close btn btn-primary">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
   var within_first_modal = false;
    $('.btn-second-modal').on('click', function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('within-first-modal')) {
        within_first_modal = true;
        $('#first-modal').modal('hide');
      }
      $('#second-modal').modal('show');
    });

    $('.btn-second-modal-close').on('click', function() {
      $('#second-modal').modal('hide');
      if (within_first_modal) {
        $('#first-modal').modal('show');
        within_first_modal = false;
      }
    });

    $('.btn-toggle-fade').on('click', function() {
      if ($('.modal').hasClass('fade')) {
        $('.modal').removeClass('fade');
        $(this).removeClass('btn-success');
      } else {
        $('.modal').addClass('fade');
        $(this).addClass('btn-success');
      }
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/NxYBwQ)

Comment: It is generally a bad practice to have a modal within a modal. With that being said, it is entirely possible to have a button inside of a modal call back to the server without a full page postback. Especially if you're using MVC.

Comment: You should be good, as long as you can use AJAX  Depending on the complexity of your application(ie. multi-step forms with different mvc.models), you may have to hard code the mapping between your bootstrap.modal form and your mvc.model.  The other big issue you may face when using MVC.Models/AJAX/Bootstrap.Modals, will be validation and error handling (UI side).

Comment: @Mark, that's a very good point in regards of validations. I don't think there will be any server-side validations (that I know of) but it is worth considering

Answer (score 0):

This would let you make a request to the server and do something with the information that you get back.

```
$(".btn-second-modal").on("click", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/urltoserver/action/",
            cache: false
        }).done(function (data) {
            // SET YOUR FIRST MODAL PROPERTIES

            // HIDE YOUR SECOND MODAL

            // SHOW YOUR FIRST MODAL
        });
    });
```

Comment: I will pass this forward and see what happens.  I'll come back to this answer after that.  Thank you